# Graph plotting in python

Tags: python

```
from SimpleCV import *

cam = Camera()
threshold = 5.0 # if mean exceeds this amount do something

while True:
        previous = cam.getImage() #grab a frame
        time.sleep(0.5) #wait for half a second
        current = cam.getImage() #grab another frame
        diff = current - previous
        matrix = diff.getNumpy()
        mean = matrix.mean()

        diff.show()

        if mean >= threshold:
                print "Motion Detected"
```

I have capture images with the rate of 2 images per second for 10 second with a camera:

now mean difference would calculated within two frames for color integral density per second: (with the help of given code above)

mean difference appeared as (for example) in the range  30-40 after every one second:

```
times                 0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9---10 

calculated mean      38  40  39   32  40  35  39  40  38 38   37
```

now i want to  plot a graph in python in real time to calculate bits per 60 second

Comment: @Torxed i was trying with Fourier transform but i got failed then i go with some simple methods like moving average but nothing is working actually methods are self sufficient but due to lack of hard core programming experience i am not able to implement these methods any help would be highly appreciated thanks

Comment: @user3218971: There are a couple of numpy questions here on calculating moving averages which contain code you can adapt (nothing hardcore). IMHO it would be best if you could decide what you want to do, seriously try to make it work, and if it doesn't come back with a specific question on some code that you have.

Comment: @user3218971 Try matplotlib or http://linil.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/cairoplot-11/ for instance.